# How Encrypt Data in android with Rsa Public Key That Generated In PHP Using PhpSeclib?

Tags: java, php, android, rsa, phpseclib

i want to create a project in android that send some data to php webservice , 
i encrypt data with a Aes Key and enrypt Aes Key with a Rsa public key that received from the server , But when i send encrypted key to server , server unable to decrypt it !

Generate Pv , PB Key in php code and send to android device :

```
<?php 
$cipher = new Crypt_RSA();
$keypairs = $cipher->createKey();
$public_key = $keypairs['publickey'];
$private_key = $keypairs['privatekey'];
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->query_result = "SUCCESS";
$obj->public_key = "$public_key";
$obj->private_key = "$private_key"; //send just for test 
echo (json_encode($obj));
```

this public and private is in Pem format ? :

```
  -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVjF8lsgjXm48cS5vj05ga1cqo KuqcyDtIcc0UBJv62jLhVo/cx/iyhcs5F+WFXjxowKZiO2rxlS6KRLY1rtuGaKF9 CVn+k8mU2Mo9QOWZINAcVTqx07fjHvRc9uOV9qqE00xl3SqmZ1NcYv9f5Y1Tynqo T0DMT+Px5Q6p9unlowIDAQAB -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Private :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXgIBAAKBgQDVjF8lsgjXm48cS5vj05ga1cqoKuqcyDtIcc0UBJv62jLhVo/c x/iyhcs5F+WFXjxowKZiO2rxlS6KRLY1rtuGaKF9CVn+k8mU2Mo9QOWZINAcVTqx 07fjHvRc9uOV9qqE00xl3SqmZ1NcYv9f5Y1TynqoT0DMT+Px5Q6p9unlowIDAQAB AoGBAMZfr8OEr1Ia38aZNidd2F6VW7z8oRUjrG6PyMJfxcYyDDHoB5xA53Zvc2mG GWDbOaLV07pNF/tzadhoHBuiY6m1q3RQzlprHwmKGGo5L60N+DGQvNsk1DXw3HYj JYkyWqOXazrW/bEl1hJcIzYAJvzKZbT1myEAF+sc+VpQ4uKBAkEA8zOJKeOeN9ow lW7xeGhK5BrzMVfpShIepAT6TYqE+mU8gFghMXUi1ExHtwZ73H23K9fYA4+RquBh FkbMI+7afwJBAODJWBGB5r6YT9bCN1LGetqGM4fwDgfeCRWZ+k/iQ/NOaFcyoJDU F5NENCZDfsPXtw4KfqM5G0/vRGyq+QeJut0CQFggYJ+xP2/1vI0puo5rHFgz+9Px izOwBTJiK2FVxIIHlTjctop5a7mKOqJz0wY+99UHTdtcduh4jjXIScjrkHkCQQCL UsBPOaB3CZiSl5YKrBKBVyShYNyRa8Fdri5DTQ6owzRQt4Rlv89M670W6karxAwl m8OaD08qYDac0+u+DFPRAkEAwQE0Ri5bmy4whpIUpPULXL+85+vds9llaCSIBZYx kQBNFp6G59EpIOvIg1AKmTiKtine3E+LoUCW+UE34DiSlw== -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And Json file that send to Android :

```
{"query_result":"SUCCESS","public_key":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDWDvcjZcgPZ+SiC9f27uD1j4Ws\r\naIdVk7FH3AgtDonGsV+nVtjmASrhXnrMWpXHfZ2gmtqh0s2yUwU4iJdNq4slUiF5\r\nM8M0IfFH2SqcBj0wVxozlF7FLNitKvtDSGzc0dKlgrw6ES9gBNvwulmDpk1dCn97\r\nV\/VUGFBf\/OdS55jA1wIDAQAB\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----","private_key":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\r\nh7arPwDXK6jI+VbiKjR9gGpffGXC6xLHzDVgbtfUThw1Wg==\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"}
```

in json file aded some \r and \n to keys , are problematic?

And this is Java Encryption method :

```
 private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromPemFormat(String PEMString) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {

        BufferedReader pemReader = null;

        pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(PEMString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----") != -1) {
                while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.indexOf("-----END PUBLIC KEY") != -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    content.append(line.trim());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (line == null) {
            throw new IOException("PUBLIC KEY" + " not found");
        }
        Log.i("PUBLIC KEY: ", "PEM content = : " + content.toString());

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(content.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT)));
        // return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(content.toString().getBytes()));


    }


 public static String getContentWithPublicKeyFromPemFormat(String PEMString,
                                                              String content, boolean ispublic) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, NoSuchProviderException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {


        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromPemFormat(PEMString);
        if (publicKey != null)
            Log.i("PUBLIC KEY: ", "FORMAT : " + publicKey.getFormat()
                    + " \ntoString : " + publicKey.toString());

        byte[] contentBytes = Base64.encode(content.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        // byte[] contentBytes = content.getBytes();

        byte[] decoded = null;

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");//BC=BouncyCastle Provider
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        decoded = cipher.doFinal(contentBytes);
        return new String(decoded, "UTF-8");

    }
```

what is Wrong ?

thanks.

Comment: Just use HTTPS, it encryptes everything except the URL address.

Comment: Your Java code is using PKCS1 padding. phpseclib uses OAEP padding by default. If you want phpseclib to use the more common PKCS1 padding you'll need to do `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`

Comment: Your code is encoding`content` as base64. You should cipher the plain AES key (`byte[]`). Your code is also returning a conversion of the encrypted key to String. This data is not String, so you can not perform the conversion. Return `byte[]` and convert to `Base64` before sending it to your server.